# Foreman install error Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: puppet, theforeman

I am not any expert, just trying to learn. I am trying to run foreman-installer on a VM but unable to complete the installation. Puppet is installed. I hope someone can help me sort this, not able to find any solution. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

This is the command I'm running:

```
foreman-installer --enable-foreman-proxy --puppet-server-puppetserver version=2.6.0 --foreman-proxy-tftp=false --foreman-proxy-dhcp=false
```

Getting this error:

> /Stage[main]/Foreman_proxy::Register/Foreman_smartproxy[manager.openstacklocal]:
>   Could not evaluate: Exception Connection refused - connect(2) for
>   "manager.openstacklocal" port 443 in get request to:
>   https://manager.openstacklocal/api/v2/smart_proxies?search=name=%22manager.openstacklocal%22

puppet config print masterport shows 8140.

Thanks!

Comment: Is `service apache2 status` running/OK? Can you open a web browser to `https://manager.openstacklocal`? The app should be running. Is `manager.openstacklocal` in DNS?

Comment: Yes apache2 is ok. Not possible to open browser to https://manager.openstacklocal

Comment: Should the DNS entry in /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
say domain-name "manager.openstacklocal"   ??

Comment: Why isn't it possible to open the web page? What's the precise cause? Is Apache listening on port 443 (`netstat -ntlp`)? I don't know that dhclient is relevant.

Comment: Web page is working now and apache is listening on port 443, but I still get the error message.

Comment: If it's precisely the same and the service is listening, then `Connection refused` suggests either a firewall is blocking access to port 443, or the name lookup for `manager.openstacklocal` is resolving to a different address than the one you expect.

Comment: It was the etc/hosts file which had the wrong ip. So its solved now.  Thank you I really appreciate your help!